# How to Get the Monthly Sales Prediction for next year using the sales history records of past 5 years?

Tags: data-mining, linear-regression, prediction, forecasting

I need to develop a system where user can analyse the past sales records and can predict monthly sales for next year. There I am using simple linear regression and get the past monthly sales records of past 5 years and create a line chart.

```
 X= month 
 y= sales
```

e.g. I get the sales of month January for 5 years and get the average and plot the graph for 12 months. So how could I give user to predict for monthly sales for next year based on the graph of linear regression equation?

Also I would like to know whether my approach is correct? or are there any efficient ways to do that?

thanks

Comment: Sorry, could not resist: The most efficient way is to [just make them up](http://dilbert.com/strip/2008-05-08).

Comment: Predicting the future based on the past is hard. You need some model. granularity is not all (here month). You should have a hypothesis, if e.g. a month aggregate of sales has something typical, like in January we always sell only half of what we sell in March. Or maybe rainy days push the sales? Or selling more 3 months ago gives a larger base of customers willing to purchase even more ... so I suggest you decide on a model (your stakeholders that make you "need develop" are good contacts) and then maybe we based on more details can help you further on your way to a working system? Thanks.

Comment: If you google for ´sales forecasting model` you'll get an infinite number of matches - regression is among the simplest. Is the aim to forecast individual products (SKUs) or groups of products or a company-total? How stable is the product-range - ie. if an SKU has 2 yrs of history only it might be more difficult to forecast...Also, you might be at the wrong place alltogether: StackOverflow is mor about fixing problems in your code - this kind of question might get better answers on other stack-forums, for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to forecasting. Your question doesn't quite belong here (as MBaas points out, stackoverflow is about teh codez), but while you are here you might as well get started with an excellent book, free and online, Rob Hyndman's *Forecasting: principles and practice*.

https://www.otexts.org/fpp

Once you have a code-related forecasting question, stackoverflow is the place for it! Hyndman even answers an occasional question here.